# CSS horizontal resize div to child elements height

Tags: css, height

I have following set up,

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
#left{
  display: inline-block;
}
#right{
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 800px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I am trying to make the container be what ever height the taller of the left or right div is. But the container is only re sizing to the height of the #left div? and when the left div's height is less than right div the right div overlaps the footer (obviously due to the min-height).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quickest solution would be to use `display: table-cell` instead. It would be something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  display:table;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#container div {
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
}
#left{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: lightgray;  
}
#right{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```